# Vue-draggable working on mobile view not in normal view?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, draggable, vue-resource

`

```html
<template>
  <div class="drag">
    <h2>Draggable</h2>
    <draggable :list="list" class="dragArea">
        <div class="noselect" v-for="element in list">{{element.name}}</div>
    </draggable>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import draggable from 'vuedraggable';

export default {
  components: {
    draggable,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      list: [
        { name: 'John' },
        { name: 'Joao' },
        { name: 'Jean' },
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss">
</style>
```

i want to make a draggable list but my list is draggable only in mobile view of chrome but it does not work in normal view. i tried the jsfiddle example it works completely fine there but it is not working on my program. above is the vue file i wrote in order to make the list draggable`

Comment: Please take the time to include your code directly in this question (not a link to an image).  Creating a complete, working example that highlights your issue in jsFiddle or CodePen would give you the best results.

Comment: i have added the snippet to the code

Comment: Actually i got the solution to the problem i had two libraries which were colliding with each other which resulted in this problem. they were veutify and one other library crashing together caused the problem.